# Create a database user and login programatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I feel like I've got something really basic wrong. I can't seem to use parameters to add a user.

The following fails with `Incorrect syntax near '@x'` :

```
var Cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE LOGIN @x FROM WINDOWS; CREATE USER @x FOR LOGIN @x", SqlConn);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", user);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Yet, this works:

```
var Cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE LOGIN @x FROM WINDOWS; CREATE USER @x FOR LOGIN @x", SqlConn);
Cmd.CommandText = Cmd.CommandText.Replace("@x", "[" + user + "]");
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(Where user is in the domain\user format: `user = @"mycomputer\myuser";`)

**Edit**
I can see through the related questions on the right that this is a duplicate. The answers say that you cannot use parameters for CREATE USER. Not sure why. Perhaps I'm supposed to be going about my base problem a different way? Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a role in my db that I want to add users to so they can access the database. I want admins to be able to do this from the software (give db access to [domain\user]) without them needing to be MR SQL and run the management studio themselves. How do I do that?

Comment: Has to do with the SQL Server.  You are trying to use a variable where one is not allowed.

Comment: Also, be careful with the second approach - you are vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Er, yes - that's the point of the question! I'm *trying* to use the first approach, but cannot!!

Answer (score 0):

[`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are supported for [*Data manipulation language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) not *[Data Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)*. Looks like you will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) in such a case

Data Definition Language

- [ALTER Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879314.aspx)
- [CREATE Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879262.aspx)
- [DISABLE TRIGGER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189748.aspx)
- [DROP Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879259.aspx)
- [ENABLE TRIGGER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182706.aspx)
- [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)
- [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187348.aspx)

Data Manipulation Language

- [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)
- [INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)
- [UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)
- [DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)